# Core PlotでX軸のデータ数とラベル数が異なる場合

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

Core Plotを用いて折れ線グラフを描画するアプリを作っています。 
CoreDataに保存された体重を日付順にグラフ化しており、 
Y軸→ 体重、X軸→ 日付 
という一般的なグラフを描画することはできます。

やりたいのは、グラフを"週間"、"月間"、"年間"で切り替える処理でして 
例えば"年間"だと、データ数は365個ですが、ラベル数は12個となります。 
ここをどのように実装したらよいかがわからず悩んでいます。

現在ラベルは以下のように指定しており

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet*)graph.axisSet;
axisSet.xAxis.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:labels]; //labels:ラベルデータ配列
axisSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
```

以下でデータ数を返しますが、
上記のラベル配列の個数とデータ数が異なると、エラーになってしまいます。

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{

    NSUInteger numRecords = 0;
    numRecords = _plotXLabelData.count;

    return numRecords;
}
```

このような場合のCore plotでの実装方法をご存知の方、ご教示いただけますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ラベルについてはUILabelで自作することで自己解決いたしました。